# JDBC - Best way for perfomance of a preparedstatement with optional criteria

Tags: java, performance, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I try to improve the performance of my application. For this, I replace the current statement by prepared-statement to use the oracle cash.

But several of my queries are dynamic (conditional criteria and tables) and I would like to know the best solution to reduce the execution time.

In stackoverflow, I found two solutions. 
The first is to build query with if statement :

```
if(a.equals("Test")) {
   whereClause.append ("COLUMN1 = ? ");
} 
if(b.equals("Test2")) {
   whereClause.append ("COLUMN2 = ? ");
} etc...
```

The second is to create one query with all criteria but to add "OR var is null"

```
where (? is null OR (COLUMN1 = ?)) AND (? is null OR (COLUMN2 = ?)) etc.
```

In your opinion what is the best way In your to performance knowing that a request may contain 40/50 criteria and some tables can be optional too. Or is there another solution.

The database that use is oracle with datasource and jdk 1.5.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First JDBC and Oracle are capable of handling and caching multiple prepared statements.

First approach:

```
if(a.equals("Test")) {
   whereClause.append ("COLUMN1 = ? ");
} 
if(b.equals("Test2")) {
   whereClause.append ("COLUMN2 = ? ");
}
```

will certainly lead to more different statements and thous to more prepared statements, but each of this statements is optimizable at preparation-time as no variable is optional.

Second approach:

```
where (? is null OR (COLUMN1 = ?)) AND (? is null OR (COLUMN2 = ?)) etc.
```

will result in exactly one prepared statement, but during prepare the query-plan needs to include the possibility that all parameters are non-null.

So it really becomes a matter of benchmarking and how many optional parameters there are. If you have too many prepared statements one might not be cached (but it might also be, that it is so seldomly used, that this does not disturb overall performance).

I also don't know how much overhead the optional parameters in the second approach create even if they are evaluated for each line as the optimizer could not remove them.

Finally if you have indexes prepared that cover some combinations of your optional parameters the first approach should be faster as during prepare the possible indexes are evaluated and the best is choosen (query-plan).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if the cache keeps the most used queries or last executed ? Because I don't undertand clearly when preparedstatement use the cache.

Comment: I would assume it is a mixture of both.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest wins in prepared statement is the query-plan (optimization) being done ahead of time. I, to be honest, doubt the optimization will be very big in case you have 20 criteria like that and only a few are actually used. Why don't you test it and see which is quickest?

Also, I think making a stored procedure out of this could be very advantageous.

Comment: Sorry, I have more criteria that 20, it's an error for my first post. In more, table can be more optional. I can't test easily because the application it's so complex. I prefer to try to get the right advice from the beginning. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use PreparedStatement with dynamic query without any additional logic. If a query repeats JDBC will find previously executed cached statement.

Comment: Ok then I try the first solution with if statement. JDBC will put in cache the query models most used ?

Comment: It depends on the driver and DBCP if you use one. Note that cache may be bound to connection, in a new connection cache will be empty

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Evgeniy, `PreparedStatements` are the way to go. If you have many parameters, the upkeep is easier if you use named parameters instead of question marks. See: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html. I have used this with about 20 criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know "named parameters"